# Install virtual webcam legacy driver via command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, device-manager

On Windows 10 I am trying to install a virtual webcam driver via **command prompt**. I have INF, CAT and SYS files, which have been signed (so that there is no need to enable test mode).

The method that works:

1. Right-click on INF file and click install and allow permissions. I get a pop up after this saying operation successful, but is not listed under **Cameras** in device manager.
2. Open Device Manager -> Add legacy hardware -> Next -> Install the hardware that I manually select from a list (Advanced) -> Cameras -> Next -> **Select required camera** -> Next
3. Once the above two steps are done, the device is listed under **Cameras** in device manager, and also I am able to view the same under the list of cameras in applications like Zoom

C:\WINDOWS\System32\InfDefaultInstall.exe **PATH-TO-INF** -> this is equivalent to Step 1.
But step 2 is what I want to achieve using commands / programmatically.

The following are methods that I have tried:

1. pnputil /add-driver  /install -> this adds the INF as oem*.inf but still not listed under cameras, still unusable
2. devcon.exe install  ROOT\CAMERA\
3. devcon.exe install **PATH-TO-INF** ROOT\CAMERA\0001
4. devcon.exe /add-driver **PATH-TO-INF**
5. devcon.exe  install vibe.inf {**CLASS-ID**}\**NameOfDriver**

None of the above are helping me to the get result I want.
The drivers are generated from a piece of code that I have taken from AVStream Hardware Sample.

Is there a command in CMD that would help me get the result I want?

Thanks in advance,
Aswin

Answer (score 0):

You can't sign individually the INF, CAT and SYS files - you need to create a
Catalog File (CAT) for your driver package that contains all the files,
then sign this CAT file.

For instructions, see the article
[How to Sign an Unsigned Driver for x64 Windows 10, 8.1 or 7 with a Self-signed Certificate](http://woshub.com/how-to-sign-an-unsigned-driver-for-windows-7-x64/).

You would be using commands such as:

```
inf2cat.exe /driver:"C:\DriverCert\xg20" /os:7_X64 /verbose
signtool sign /f C:\DriverCert\myDrivers.pfx /p P@ss0wrd /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /v C:\DriverCert\xg20\xg20gr.cat
```

I would just remark that a self-signed certificate can only be made to work
in your own computer, by adding your certificate to the local computer
certificate store.

Comment: The issue is about installing the driver, not signing. The set of files has been signed by Windows, not signed individually. I will re-word it.